# How i can i get text from tag ul

Tags: javascript, html

How to i get text  from tag

And check if i press it or not

```
 <ul id="menu">
    <li><div>####</div></li>
    <li><div>####</div></li>
    <li><div>####</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div>####</div></li>
        <li><div>####</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

---

```
       $( "#menu ul" ).on( "click", function() {
inputValue = $("#menu ul").val()
  document.write(inputValue );
});
```

Comment: `$("#menu > li > div").on("click", function() { document.write($(this).val()) })`

Comment: do you need to display the entire `ul` or `li` tags separately?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes